# Giving a beautiful orchid as a Christmas gift to your mother?

Tags: orchids

What rather rare and colourful orchid that you can't find in supermarkets could I order on Amazon as a Christmas gift for my mother?

Comment: Unless your mother is an orchid addict and grows many of them in a hothouse, a rare orchid might not be a good present. Those orchids sold in supermarkets are there because they make relatively easy care houseplants in ordinary rooms,but a lot of orchids, especially the more exotic kinds, need particular conditions to thrive which are not found in the home.

Comment: I think the orchids at the grocery stores are pretty much a one time thing , they last well but generally do not get the conditions necessary for re-bloom. Yes , I know many people on this site get them to re-bloom , but that is a small fraction of the total sold.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I don't think that's true of Phalaenopsis, or Moth Orchid, which is the one you usually see in supermarkets - I've got friends who've had theirs for around five years, reblooming too, without anything other than minimal care of the order that's required for any houseplant.

Comment: @Bamboo you should create an answer, I would be happy to upvote it!

Comment: Well it doesn't really answer your question, does it,that's why I did it as a comment...but if you think  its a helpful response, I';ll post it so you can close the question if you want?

Comment: @Bamboo Yes you can do it:) thank you!

Comment: An easier-to-grow showy plant is any amaryllis. They live outside during the growing season, come inside before frost (and don't need watering at that point), and finally, after a few months' rest, some watering will set them to blooming. It takes about 6-7weeks after first watering for the plant to bloom, so it i possible to time this for Christmas, Valentine's Day, or Easter. I once timed one my plants to bloom on my daughter's wedding in Mid-May.

Comment: You do know that lots of plants being sold on Amazon and Ebay are fake or false advertising.   You need to make sure their comments and reviews are good.  I have reported fake plants to Amazon and they do nothing about it, because their not Amazon guaranteed items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your mother is already an orchid addict and grows many of them in a hothouse, a rare orchid might not be a good present. Orchids sold in supermarkets (usually Phalaeonopsis or moth orchid) are there because they make relatively easy care houseplants in ordinary rooms, but a lot of orchids, especially the more exotic kinds, need particular conditions to thrive which are not found in the home.